# Is there a way to check if a location (longitude, latitude) is within a pre-defined polygon?

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gis

I want to be able to split my city into `N` polygons and check if a given address (converted to longitude and latitude) is within any of the polygons. I know it is possible to do client-side, but is there a server-side (Java, if it makes any difference) way to to the requested?

Comment: Have you checked out [Java Topology Suite](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm) ?

Comment: @Sid, I didn't know it exists

Comment: Let me post that as an answer then .. \

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Java Topology Suite](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm) should do what you want. There's also a JSTS (JavaScript Topology Suite). Since you haven't specified that you want to only use google's API's. These should be good enough..

Comment: That seems to do exactly what I want! Do you happen to know of any tool that can help me draw and prepare those polygons?

Comment: When you say draw, where exactly are you drawing them ? If its the frontend then google's API's should take care of it.. assuming you want to use Google's API's.

Comment: I want to draw the polygons on a map, and then use the coordinates given by that tool to check if the input coordinates are within these polygons.

Comment: You should have a look at [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) .. as mentioned in my answer the JSTS should also be useful.